# How can I bind distinct playlist title from database to checkbox list

Tags: asp.net

```
private void chkDeletePlaylistBind()      
{     
   chkDeletePlaylist.DataSource = objEntities.Playlists.OrderBy(del => del.PlaylistTitle).Distinct();
   chkDeletePlaylist.DataTextField = "PlaylistTitle";
   chkDeletePlaylist.DataValueField = "PlaylistID";
   chkDeletePlaylist.DataBind();
}
```

It does not brings the distinct values to the check box list. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Perhaps due to this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects) (`Distinct` compare the reference...)?

Comment: Have you thus try one of the answers in the topic mentioned above and does this works now?

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie sorry for the late reply. issue is fixed