# The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I wonder why I am not able to find this error on stackoverflow. In Linq to SQL, i am selecting an anonymous object like

```
var something = from a in .....
    ......
    ......
    select new 
    { 
        myParameter = a.Something 
        myListParameter = (from b in ........
                           select b)
    }
.
.
.
.
something = something.Distinct(); //This is giving error
```

In selecting anonymous type object above, in one of the properties I am selecting another list. I guess this might be causing the issue. I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be because your query is returning more than one result,

try using

```
something = something.Distinct().ToList();
```

You can use a workaround if applicable to your requirements .

```
something = something.GroupBy(x => x.PropertyToCompare).Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui Please check if this workaround helps you .

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to Distinct() an anonymous type as each object will be held in different memory space, and therefore not equatable.

You will likely need to implement IEquatable to use Distinct() as per this response: [Distinct not working with LINQ to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects)

Comment: but that is Linq to Objects, I know that implementing an IEquatable will solve the problem, but I can't define one for Anonymous types or can I?

Comment: Correct - pretty much the only way then is to group then first(), which technically isn't a distinct, rather the first of each group. If you have data that is different in non-compared fields, then your results will differ.

Comment: the answer was sufficiently workable in my case, we have primary keys in our table and I just grouped the data on that field.