# Trying to select elements by child element

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C#...

I have this XML in variable 'myXml':

```
<root>
<article><title>A1</title><category><title>Geography</title></category></article>
<article><title>A2</title><category><title>History</title></category></article>
<article><title>A3</title><category><title>Geography</title></category></article>
<article><title>A4</title><category><title>Finance</title></category></article>
</root>
```

How can I retrieve each  which has a category title of "Finance" using LINQ2XML, as either a lambda or plain LINQ query?

I have this LINQ query which does not work:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(myXml);

var l = (from d in doc.Elements("root").Elements("article")
                    where d.Elements("category").Elements("title").Equals("Finance")
                    select d);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not work.

Comment: name? instead title. Wait a second, i'm trying to done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine:

```
        var query = from article in doc.Descendants("article")
                    where ((string)article.Element("category").Element("title").Value == "Finance")
                    select article;
```

The method `Equals` is not for comparison with other object by your parameter. Please look here:
[Distinct not working with LINQ to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Simple XPath solution will be

```
 var l = doc.XPathSelectElements("/root/article[category/title/text() = \"Finance\"]");
```

Alernatively,

```
var l = (from d in elem.Element("root")
            .Elements("article")
            .Elements("category")
            .Elements("title")
            .Where(x => x.Value == "Finance")
            select d.Parent.Parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it for you

```
 var l = from att in XDocument.Parse(myXml)
                .Element("root")
                .Elements("article")
                .Elements("category")
                .Where(x => x.Value == "Finance")
                select att;
```