# Distinct() linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to filter my linq query, using `distinct()` method but I keep getting all the data records (including duplication).  I have tried the following variations, which all seem to be failing.

```
           int total = Data.Count();

           // Data = Data.GroupBy(member => member.Tag).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Name).First());

           // Data = Data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);

            Data = Data.Distinct().OrderBy(value => value.Tag);

            var data = Data.ToList();
```

How can I filter my query by showing all the data fieldnames which are filtered by unique `tags` field name?  My `tag` fieldname does contain `NULL` data as well.

**Here is my entire method, for further reference:**

```
        [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
   private HttpResponseMessage method(HttpContext request, Query query)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("admin") || User.IsInRole("art"))
        {
            IQueryable<database_B> Data = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
            {
                var ids = query.name.Split(',');

               // var dataMatchingTags = db.database_B.Where(c => ids.Any(id => c.Name.Contains(id)));

                if (Data == null)
                    Data = dataMatchingTags;
                else
                    Data = Data.Union(dataMatchingTags);
            }

            if (Data == null) // If no tags or name is being queried, apply filters to the whole set of products
                Data = db.database_B;

            if (query.endDate != null)
            {
                Data = Data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate);
            }

            if (query.startDate != null)
            {
                Data = Data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
            }

            int total = Data.Count();

           // Data = Data.GroupBy(member => member.Tag).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Name).First());

           // Data = Data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);

            Data = Data.Distinct().OrderBy(value => value.Tag);

            var data = Data.ToList();

            if (!data.Any())
            {
                var message = string.Format("No data found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }

           // return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { total, data });
        }
```

Thank you for any further help.

Comment: How do you declare your `Data` type?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  `IQueryable<database_B> Data = null;`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: And how is `database_B` type declared?

Comment: `database_B` is the database entity framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct not working with LINQ to Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that ?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert

Answer (score 0):

If `database_B` is a `class` (as opposed to a `struct`) which does not implement `IEquatable<database_B>` in a suitable way, `Distinct` will treat different objects as different, regardless of member values. A possible solution would be to implementet `IEquatable<database_B>` to reflect the comparision which is desired for equality.

Alternatively, a different overload of `Distinct` can be used, where it is possible to give a custom comparision as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `database_B` has to implement Equals- and GetHashCode-Method in order to tell the `Distinct` under which circumstances two instances are considered equal and may therefor be filtered out.