# Unable to return distinct data using linq

Tags: linq

I have a global variable list called objCustomerData
I want to be able to return distinct data in GetBranch method.

This is not happening. It is returning all the duplicates. I want it to 
return just distinct branches.

Please what am I doing wrong here?

```
        private List<Customer> objCustomerData;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            InventoryAssViewModel objModel = new InventoryAssViewModel();
            try
            {   
                 if (countryValue == "CA")
                {
                    objCustomerData = _inventoryService.GetListCountryData("CAA");

                    objModel.BranchModel = GetBranch();
                }
                else 
                {
                    objCustomerData = _inventoryService.GetListCountryData("NIG");                 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return View(objModel);
        }


        public List<Branch> GetBranch()
        {
            List<Branch> filterBranch;

            try
            {
                filterBranch = (from c in objCustomerData
                    select new Branch()
                    {
                        Id = c.Branch,
                        BranchName = c.Branch
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {               
                throw;
            }
            return filterBranch;
        }
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects

Comment: This is not helpful. Unable to get this to work. What about groupby?

Comment: Can you show us what the signature of the class `Branch` looks like?

Comment: *Unable to get this to work* isn't very useful. The link provided by har07 is exactly what you should do. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
filterBranch = objCustomerData.Select(c => c.Branch).Distinct().Select(c => new Branch()
{
    Id = c,
    BranchName = c
})).ToList();
```

Or

```
filterBranch = objCustomerData.GroupBy(x => x.Branch).Select(c => new Branch()
{
    Id = c.Key,
    BranchName = c.Key
})).ToList();
```

Comment: @user2320476, It is not possible, even GroupBy also returning duplicates? May be the data have spaces or some other characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either implement `IEquatable<T>` on the `Branch` class or, assuming that `Branch.Branch` is a string, you can utilize the fact that the C# compiler generates both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the anonymous types:

```
var filteredBranch = objCustomerData.Select(c =>
 new
 {
     Id = c.Branch,
     BranchName = c.Branch
 }).Distinct().Select(c =>
 new Branch()
 {
     Id = c.Id,
     BranchName = c.BranchName
 }).ToList();
```

Performance wise the second approach should be slower, because you are creating more objects, first the anonymous objects, then the `Branch` objects. But it won't make much difference, if you are dealing with a relatively small collection.